# How do I find CMD Properties window in Windows 11?

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-11

In Windows 10 and earlier, opening a CMD window and right clicking on the title bar brought up a Window titled CMD Properties.

[image]

When I do that in Windows 11, I get a new tab titled Settings, but with a heading Startup.

[image]

Is it possible to get the old window back?  There is no Properties button to click on:

[image]

Right-clicking the top left icon gives:

[image]

I typed CMD at the magnifying glass and got:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the older CMD Properties, you need to change the Terminal Windows to a CMD Window.  I am using Windows 11 Pro 23H2.

I have done this because I prefer it.

Open the Windows Terminal Settings interface by launching Windows Terminal. Click on the downward arrow icon situated on the top bar of the Terminal window.

Then click on the ‘Settings’ option from the resulting menu.

In the Startup section set the Default Profile to Command Prompt. Save this and exit.

Now you should have a Command Prompt that opens as CMD used to open. The Command Prompt has Properties like the prior CMD prompt did.

You may also wish to / need to open cmd.exe to get the Command Prompt window that allows properties. You can do this by searching for the Command Prompt App using the magnifier icon on the task bar.

.

[image: Windows CMD Properties]

Comment: The SAVE button is down at the bottom of the Main Terminal screen in Blue. Try that again.  Also try running CMD.EXE   as that ensures getting the proper command prompt.  My Start Button shortcut is to cm.exe  .   I added that to my answer.

Comment: My Default Profile was already Command Prompt, and Settings just open that useless tab.  Where do I find Properties?

Comment: Try opening cmd.exe  (click on the magnifier in the task bar and type cmd  . It will show you Command Prompt App.   Use that and Properties are where I showed in my answer. You need to use the older way to get what you want.

Comment: Just did exactly that.  I have the Command Prompt window up, but I don't see Properties anywhere. Settings just bring ups the useless extra tab.  Where do "Click on Properties" as you suggest?

Comment: Top left button on the command prompt

Comment: The little black CMD icon?  If I right-click on that, I get Color, Rename Tab, Duplicate Tab. Split Tab, Export Text, Find, Close, Close Tab.  No Properties.

Comment: I can't add screenshots here, so I have added them to the main question.  I don't see the word "Properties" anywhere.

Comment: Your screen shot is the Terminal Window and not the Command Prompt Window (Command Prompt App.

Comment: I typed CMD in the magnifying glass and got that.  Image above.

Comment: So that should bring up the Command Window and not the Terminal Window.

Comment: Just doing what you told me. That's exactly what I've been doing all afternoon to get all the screen shots above.  No Properties anywhere.  It does not work for me...

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong with your OS.  I have 3 Production Windows 11 Pro 23H2 machines and what I posted works properly on all.

Comment: ok thanks, maybe some registry setting.